# Including winforms installer in UppercuT code_drop

Tags: winforms, build

Does anyone know how to specifically include a winforms setup project to be included in the code_drop folder generated when running UppercuTs zip.bat? With the default settings my web applications and WCF services are included, as are the dll's for the solutions core, but not my winforms application/installer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just playing around with UppercuT last night, and I ran into the same question.

One tip I found for putting console apps and windows services into the code_drop is to use this Nuget package in your console/windows service projects:

http://nuget.org/packages/publishedapplications

See this for more info:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_reynolds/archive/2011/03/22/published-applications-aka-publishedapplications.aspx

Using this will cause your console/windows service projects to be "published" similary to how a web app is published in the code_drop.  However, this isn't what you're asking for, just wanted to point it out if its useful.  This also doesn't work for installers.

If your installers are using the default Visual Studio setup projects (.vdproj projects), I haven't tried that, so I can't help there.  I do know that MSBuild refuses to build those types of projects (not sure why...), so you might be better off using WiX or another installer technology.  You can do an automated build on a vdproj if you run the build by calling devenv.exe directly from the command line, but you can't build those with MSBuild.  I did try adding a WiX setup project to my sln, and UppercuT will build the Wix setup project and drop the .msi in the "build_output" folder, but it doesn't copy it over to the code_drop.  My thought would be to add a custom post build step to just copy that file over from build_output to code_drop.  I haven't had a chance to figure out the logic in the build scripts to see how it chooses which files to copy from build_output to code_drop.  If I figure anything out, I'll update this answer.

Comment: Thanks man, had a play with this and it doesnt work for the problem that I had, but it has helped me out with a couple of console apps that I'd moreorless given up on and have been deploying manually for a few months, so thanks, great find!

Comment: It turns out Uppercut does copy Wix .msis into code_drop.  My problem was user error - Uppercut does not copy artifacts from build_output to code_drop if they contain the word "Test" or something like that (to exclude unit test binaries, etc.).  My .msi project was something like WixTest.msi, so it was excluded for that reason.  I created a different msi like "Setup.msi" and it got copied to code_drop.